# IAP restore state firing incorrectly

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, restore

I currently have a restore button on my IAP screen, however after passing apple submission and going live, my friend tested it on his device, when he did so he was able to restore the purchase without ever having made the purchase in the first place, now when i debug the code i have noticed that hitting restore runs this completion delegate method, which in turn runs my method to unlock certain functionality.

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue
```

My code is as follows:

```
 #pragma mark Restore Purchases
#pragma mark -
-(void)restorePurchaseIAP{

    // ask to restore
    [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue] restoreCompletedTransactions];

}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver
#pragma mark -
-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue updatedTransactions:(NSArray *)transactions
{
    for (SKPaymentTransaction *transaction in transactions)
    {
        switch (transaction.transactionState) {
            case SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased:
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]
                 finishTransaction:transaction];
                [delegate itemPurchased];
                break;

            case SKPaymentTransactionStateFailed:
                [delegate itemPurchasedFailed];
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
                case SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored:
                NSLog(@"restored state");
                [[SKPaymentQueue defaultQueue]finishTransaction:transaction];
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
    }
}

#pragma mark SKPaymentTransactionObserver
#pragma mark -
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue{
        NSLog(@"restored state Completed");
    [delegate purchaseRestored];

}

-(void)paymentQueue:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue restoreCompletedTransactionsFailedWithError:(NSError *)error{
    NSLog(@"restore has FAILED");

}
```

This occurs even if i am not logged in with a user account for apple. I also noticed that the first time i debugged this on my friends device if i tried to make the purchase, then cancelled when i was prompted with the IAP price and confirmation, the restore button would then restore the purchase.

Am i right in thinking that when i call the restoreCompletedTransactions, apple should only confirm and run the:

```
- (void)paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:(SKPaymentQueue *)queue{
```

Method if the IAP has already been purchased, or am i supposed to be doing a check for the pack somewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StoreKit/Reference/SKPaymentTransactionObserver_Protocol/index.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/SKPaymentTransactionObserver/paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished:) `paymentQueueRestoreCompletedTransactionsFinished` for states

> Tells the observer that the payment queue has finished sending
>   restored transactions.
>
> **Discussion**
>
> This method is called after all restorable transactions have been processed by the payment queue. Your application is not required to do anything in this method.

So this method indicates that no more restoration transactions will be sent (This may be after 0 restoration transactions were sent in the case of no transactions to restore or not logged in).

You cannot determine anything about the state of purchases in this method, so it is not valid to unlock functionality based on its invocation.  You should unlock functionality in `updatedTransactions:` for states `SKPaymentTransactionStatePurchased` and `SKPaymentTransactionStateRestored`

Comment: Hi Paul, thanks for your help, i've made the change and it does appear to work.